# How to apply Linear Gradient background to all React Navigation screens?

Tags: typescript, expo, react-navigation, native-base

I want to use `LinearGradient` component from "`expo-linear-gradient"` that behaves as a background in all of my screen stack. How can I achieve this?

Please see my stack configuration in App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("Titles");

  return (
    <Provider store={store}> // redux
      <NativeBaseProvider theme={nativeBaseTheme}> // native base wrapper. maybe a solution here?
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            // a possible wrapper as a background for all the screens?
            <Stack.Screen
              name="HomePage"
              component={HomePage}
              options={{ title: t("1") as string }} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Settings"
              component={Settings}
              options={{ title: t("2") as string }} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Sign Up"
              component={SignUp}
              options={{
                title: t("3") as string
              }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

*(the function `t` is just for translation, please disregard that)*

I tried to override the `DefaultTheme` from `"@react-navigation/native"` but the background field there only accepts `string`. So it doesn't work.

If I wrap one of my functional component, for example `SignUp`, in `LinearGradient`, it works. But that way I repeat my code which is a bad practice and makes it difficult to scale the app.

I read [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376171/setting-an-expo-lineargradient-as-background-of-the-whole-react-native-app) but the solution I guess is outdated and it doesn't work for me.

I am from React background, not Native so it's really confusing to me. I'd be glad for any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solution was easy:

```
export default function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("Titles");

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NativeBaseProvider theme={nativeBaseTheme}>
        <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
          <LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            height: '100%'
          }} /> // <-- Put the LinearGradient here, under NavigationContainer
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="HomePage"
              component={HomePage}
              options={{
                title: t("1") as string
              }} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Settings"
              component={Settings}
              options={{ title: t("2") as string }} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Sign Up"
              component={SignUp}
              options={{
                title: t("3") as string
              }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>

      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </Provider >
  );
}
```